# Does there exist a closed set that is not semi-open?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

A subset $A$ of a topological space $(X,T)$ is said to be semi-open if there exist an open set $B \in ( X,T)$ such that  $B \subseteq A \subseteq  \overline B$.

Now my question is that

Give an example of a closed set that is not necessarily a semi-open set.

My attempt : I think about closed interval  $A=[0,1]$ and $A= \mathbb{R}$ all are satisfied the semi-open properties.

I think such kind example doesn't exist.

Comment: Consider the singleton: the only open subset contained in it is $\emptyset$, and the closure of the emptyset is the emptyset itself.

Comment: okk@quangtu123 is there any other example  ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z \cup [0,1]$ is a closed set and not a semi-open set

Comment: Any closed set that has empty interior. Examples in $\mathbb R^2$ are straight lines, closed line segments, circles, … Moreover, any union of such a set with any closed set of which it is not a subset. For example, the union of the closed unit disk with a straight line. Or the union of any closed set and a single point outside that set.

Comment: Note that the last example in my previous comment was still assuming $\mathbb R^2$ as underlying space. Actually it will work in any Hausdorff space without isolated points, but it will not work if the chosen point is an isolated point of the space (that is, the singleton is open — for example, all singletons in the discrete metric are open), and it may fail in general spaces (as singletons need not be closed there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like quangtu123 said, every closed subset with empty interior does the trick. If you want something in $\Bbb{R}$ which is not just a singleton or something similar, I would suggest looking at [the Canot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a closed set which is not a semi-open set. Then $\overline{A^\circ}\neq A$ (since otherwise it would suffice to pick $B=A^\circ$). Conversely, if $\overline{A^\circ}\neq A$, then for any open subset $B\subset A$, we have $B\subset A^\circ$ (since $A^\circ$ is the maximal open subset of $A$), and therefore $\overline{B}\subset\overline{A^\circ}\subsetneq A$. Hence we have:

**Proposition** - Let $A$ be a closed set. Then $A$ is a semi-open subset if and only if $\overline{A^\circ}=A$.

Your question can be rephrased as: find closed subsets $A$ such that $\overline{A^\circ}\neq A$; which means $\exists p\in A:p\notin\overline{A^\circ}$; which means $\exists p\in A$ such that $p$ and $A^\circ$ are separated (by open subsets). Suggested by the terminology *nowhere dense subset*, such a set might be called *not dense somewhere*. Obviously all non-empty nowhere dense subsets are not dense somewhere (i.e. the case of empty interior).

In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, an isolated point in the set would suffice.